# Fail to Star Child in APACHE 9.0 Windows

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, docbase

10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.859 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\balancer.xml]
10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.860 WARNING [main] org.apache.cata**strong text**lina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/balancer] in deployment descriptor [C:\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\balancer.xml] has been ignored
10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.867 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [C:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\balancer] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.892 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.906 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\balancer.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1830)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@54e041a4]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4792)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\balancer] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:751)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 41 more
10-Jun-2020 18:11:00.916 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\balancer.xml] has finished in [57] ms

Comment: ...and your question is? See [ask] and edit your question please

Comment: Kindly give a brief description after title and properly format the code and refer "How to Ask" as mentioned by @OlafKock